# Override a JUnit annotation?

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I have a method I call in my superclass like so:

```
public class superClass {
  @Before
  void createDriver(){
    driverFactory = new FirefoxDriverFactory();
  }
  ...
}
```

However, in my test suite specifically which inherits from the super class, I want it so that I can run my test with the `@BeforeClass` annotation and not the `@Before` annotation. I'm not sure, but is it possible to override the `@Before` annotation or not? I tried the following:

```
public class derivedClass extends superClass{
  @Override
  @BeforeClass
  void createDriver(){
    driverFactory = new FirefoxDriverFactory();
  }
}
```

But I get an error that says that the `createDriver()` method must be static and I must remove the `@Override` annotation. Is it possible to Override an annotation as opposed to a function? I was just wondering. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Java method annotations work in conjunction with method overriding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082619/how-do-java-method-annotations-work-in-conjunction-with-method-overriding)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in annotation overrides. JUnit requires @BeforeClass method to be static:

```
public class derivedClass extends superClass{

  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass(){
   driverFactory = new FirefoxDriverFactory();
  }
}
```

Comment: This only works if OP is OK with both methods being invoked. I believe the question is to have `derivedClass`'s method overload `superClass`'s.

Comment: Yes, you can override super method and JUnit will call it. But you cannot put `@BeforeClass` annotation on overloaded method. It's okay for JAVA compiler but JUnit requirements is method anotated with `@BeforeClass` should be static.

Comment: My point is that if the OP wanted to override the behavior, the correct solution is not to fix the use of `@BeforeClass`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you might be looking for...

```
public class superClass {
  @Before
  void createDriver(){
    driverFactory = new FirefoxDriverFactory();
  }
  ...
}

public class derivedClass extends superClass{
  @Override
  void createDriver(){
    driverFactory = new FirefoxDriverFactory();
  }
}
```

JUnit should find `superClass.createDriver()` via the annotation. However, when this method is invoked on an instance of `derivedClass` the actual method that should be run is `derivedClass.createDriver()` since this method overloads the other. Try it and let us know.