# Java reflection: Find base class/interface a method was declared in

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a public API like:

```
interface Alien {
    @Help( "Make him say something" )
    String speak();
}
```

and an implementation like:

```
class Dalek implements Alien {
    @Override
    String speak(){ return "Exterminate!"; }
}
```

Now I need to access the Annotation `@Help` on the base interface but I only have the implementation / derived class which may implements other interfaces or extend other classes, too.

So is there a sane way in Java to find the "base" method which is overridden or another way to get to that annotation?

Pseudocode for what I'm looking for would be like:

```
Method m;

m.getDeclaringMethod().getAnnotation( Help.class );

// or:

m.getAnnotationRecusively( Help.class )
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082619/how-do-java-method-annotations-work-in-conjunction-with-method-overriding

Comment: No. It is not. That questions asks to get explained how annotations work. The answer explains that annotations aren't inherited. My questions is how to get to them anyway (or more general to overriden methods.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no “sane way” to do this regarding interfaces. The problem is that there is no unique “base” method. A method declaration may override a super class method and implement multiple unrelated interface methods at the same time, e.g.

```
class A {
    public void foo() {}
}
interface I1 {
    void foo();
}
interface I2 {
    void foo();
}
class B extends A implements I1, I2 {
    @Override
    public void foo() {}
}
```

Then, when you use this naive approach:

```
public static void printCandidates(Method m) {
    Class<?> cl=m.getDeclaringClass();
    String name=m.getName(); Class<?>[] param=m.getParameterTypes();
    for(Class<?> i: cl.getInterfaces()) try {
        Method ifM=i.getMethod(name, param);
        System.out.println("candidate "+ifM.getDeclaringClass().getName()+'.'+name);
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
    for(;;) {
        System.out.println("candidate "+cl.getName()+'.'+name);
        cl=cl.getSuperclass();
        if(cl==null) break;
        try { m=cl.getMethod(name, param); }
        catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) { break; }
    }
}
```

and invoke `printCandidates(new B().getClass().getMethod("foo"));`, it will print

```
candidate I1.foo
candidate I2.foo
candidate B.foo
candidate A.foo
```

but note that interfaces support multiple inheritance and also redundant `implements` specifications, e.g. you may change above scenario as

```
interface I3 extends I2, I1 {
}
interface I4 extends I2 {
    void foo();
}
class B extends A implements I3, I4, I2 {
    @Override
    public void foo() {}
}
```

and we will get

```
candidate I2.foo
candidate I4.foo
candidate I2.foo
candidate B.foo
candidate A.foo
```

Note, how the declaration `I2.foo` appears twice, but when `I4.foo` has an annotation, it should have precedence as it overrides `I2.foo`, whereas `I1.foo` doesn’t appear but needs to be considered and is not overridden. The entire logic for supporting multiple inheritance, potentially redundantly specified interfaces and some interfaces containing overriding specifications is quite complex. But it gets worse:

```
class B extends A implements I3, I4, I2 {
}
```

After making this change, we get:

```
candidate A.foo
```

and nothing else. `B` is implementing all the interfaces using the method inherited from `A`, so when looking up the method `foo` in `B` we get a `Method` object reporting `A` as its declaring class, which doesn’t implement any interface. So a `Method` object is not capable of carrying the required type of information for your intended lookup. The annotation search method needs more information than that, if it ought to find all interface method candidates, e.g. you may need to pass the actual `Class` explicitly.

---

Note that ordinary Java operations don’t need to deal with such a complexity. You may invoke an interface method on an actual object and regardless of how complex the interface inheritance hierarchy is, the implementation method is searched on the concrete class of the object, traversing the linear superclass hierarchy when necessary (the new `default` methods change this a bit, but it’s still simpler as your task, as overridden methods still are irrelevant for invocation).

An implementation for your kind of task is not provided by the JRE.

Comment: Hi Holger. Thanks for your comprehensive answer and for pointing out that in Java there is no such concept of a single "declaration". Just a few things: 1. The "naive" code isn't printing what you say it does. 2. I think it is possible to get it less naive if called recursively.

Comment: Indeed. I made changes after copying the code and forgot to copy it again. Of course, you may collect all methods/interfaces recursively, but, as I tried to explain, you may encounter the same types multiple times due to the possibility of inheriting multiple interfaces having the same supertype. *Then* you have to find out which one conceptionally overrides another, if you prefer the annotation of the overriding method, if present.