# How does Spring Boot recognize @Scheduled on a subclass' method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's take an example of a simple Spring Boot program:

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

SuperClass.java

```
public abstract class SuperClass {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("this is the super method");
    }
}
```

SubClass.java

```
@Component
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082619/how-do-java-method-annotations-work-in-conjunction-with-method-overriding/10082663#10082663) answer, only annotations annotated by `@Inherited` are inherited by subclasses, and [@Scheduled](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) does not have such an annotation. So how come this is working?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`@Inherited`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) only applies to class types, not methods.

> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
>   type is used to annotate anything other than a class. Note also that
>   this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from
>   superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.

When Spring scans beans for the `@Scheduled` annotation (or others), it looks for all methods in the bean class. `SubClass` has a `printSomething` so Spring decides it can enhance it with the scheduling behavior.

---

Spring handles `@Scheduled` a little differently than the standard proxying mechanism and is able to invoke `private` methods annotated with it.

Had you overriden the `printSomething` method in the subclass and omitted the `@Scheduled` annotation on that declaration, Spring would not have applied the scheduling behavior.

Comment: I see. So in the answer I've linked to, the foo() method wasn't invoked because it had overridden the super method. Thanks for the clarification.