# default annotation for method of an interface

Tags: java, interface, annotations, java-annotations

I have an interface:

```
public interface PermissionCallback {
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    void grantedPermission(String permission);

    void deniedPermission(String permission);
}
```

and I want when I implement it, by default add `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` on overridden method. like this:

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
public void grantedPermission(String permission) {
   //...
}
```

Can anyone tell me, why it doesn't add?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745798/why-java-classes-do-not-inherit-annotations-from-implemented-interfaces/4745820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotation on methods aren't inherited  as properly explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10082663/9485283) 
answer though if you want to check if the method have the annotation you can explicity write a custom function that will do it for you, also well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10673761/9485283)